# simple script transposing table

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to write a script, that just transposes a CSV table.
I have some file:

```
head1;head2;head3
field11;field12;field13
field21;field22;field23
```

(and so on.), and I want

```
head1;field11;field21
head2;field12;field22
head3;field13;field23
```

I don't even haven't any idea about how it may be done.
I don't ask you to write a script, I need an idea about how I can make it in a standard shell (unfortunately I'm not able to use bashism or GNU extensions, POSIX only)

ps. Actually, I can do it, but only in an ugly and inefficient way. I believe there is a more beautiful way.

Answer (score 3):

Transposing the data

```
head1;head2;head3
field11;field12;field13
field21;field22;field23
field31;field32;field33
```

can be done with GNU `datamash`:

```bash
$ datamash -t ';' transpose <file
head1;field11;field21;field31
head2;field12;field22;field32
head3;field13;field23;field33
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick adaptation of [the bash solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763972/863042) to [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash) for the  particular separators you have (semicolons):

```
declare -a array=( )                      # we build a 1-D-array

IFS=';' read -a line < "$1"                       # read the headline

COLS=${#line[@]}                          # save number of columns

index=0
while IFS=';' read -a line ; do
    for (( COUNTER=0; COUNTER<${#line[@]}; COUNTER++ )); do
        array[$index]=${line[$COUNTER]}
        ((index++))
    done
done < "$1"

for (( ROW = 0; ROW < COLS; ROW++ )); do
  printf "%s" ${array[$ROW]}
  for (( COUNTER = ROW+COLS; COUNTER < ${#array[@]}; COUNTER += COLS )); do
    printf ";%s" ${array[$COUNTER]}
  done
  printf "\n" 
done
```

Comment: PS. Actually solution with awk that is in SO works much better. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @rush Yes, `awk` is much faster in this kind of operations. It is definitely worth learning! I myself don't know it well enough yet, so I proposed a `bash` way.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is semicolon-separated (not CSV). As such you can try this code:

```
awk -F';' '{OFS=";"}{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]= (i in a?a[i] OFS :"") $i; } 
    END{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print a[i] }' input.txt

head1;field11;field21;field31
head2;field12;field22;field32
head3;field13;field23;field33
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flds=3; for((i=1;i<=flds;i++));do
  printf '%s' "$(cut -d';' -f$i file)" |tr '\n' ';';echo
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the solution I'm looking for. In this case I need read file as many times as columns I have. It's useful only for small files. Not my case.